# jpa retrieving date from oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

hi i need to retrieve the data from the oracle Database which has DATE values, i have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GRUPO_HORARIO_FICHA")
public class grupo_horario {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COD_GRUPO_HORARIO")
    private String codigo;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME) //tried DATE,TIME and TIMESTAMP already
    @Column(name = "HORA_INI")
    private Date hora_ini; //java.util.Date

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME) //tried DATE,TIME and TIMESTAMP already
    @Column(name = "HORA_FIN") 
    private Date hora_fin; //java.util.Date
```

so when i call the following method in the DAO i get null as the date values:

```
grupo_horario grupo_horarios= new grupo_horario();
        try {
        grupo_horarios = (grupo_horario) em.createQuery("SELECT g FROM grupo_horario g WHERE g.codigo = :codigo").setParameter("codigo", codigo).getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {return null; }


        System.out.println("el resultado date=" + grupo_horarios.getCodigo()); // i get the id with no problem at all.
        System.out.println("el resultado date=" + grupo_horarios.getHora_ini()); // i get null here, i need to retrieve the time.
```

the DATE columns in the database should be DATE and not TIMESTAMP, the Dates i have are java.util.Date. im using ojdbc6 and oracle database 10g if that information is needed

Comment: What is the type of hora_ini , i mean is it java.sql.Date or java.util.Date?

Comment: How you store date into database?

Comment: @RajuSharma hora_ini is java.util.Date

Comment: @JaySmith right now is from a already built database so im retrieving data directly, im going to store date later.

Comment: If you working with oracle allways use one of TemporalType  annotation. `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP`  or `TemporalType.Date` or `TemporalType.Time`

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz ive tried with the 3 options already and i keep getting null

Comment: Try with date, or timestamp

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz already tried with TIME,DATE,TIMESTAMP

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-enums-attribute-converter

Answer (score 0):

looks like my table column was HORA_INICIO and that seemed to be the problem just changed it and its working.